# If $A^k=O$ for some $k\ge 2$ does it necessarily imply that $I+A$ is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A\in M_{n } \left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ is a non zero nilpotent matrix, i.e $A^k=O$ for some positive integer $k\ge 2$. Is $I+A$ necessarily invertible?

**What I attempted:-**

We have,  $\rho(I+A)\le \rho(I)+\rho(A)=3+\rho(A)$  $\quad$ [$\rho(A)$ means the rank of $A$]

Again, $\rho(I)=3=\rho(I+A-A)\le \rho(I+A)+\rho(-A)$
Thus, $3-\rho(-A) \le \rho(I+A) \le 3+ \rho(A)$

Or, $3-\rho(A) \le \rho(I+A) \le 3+ \rho(A)$
By the condition of nilpotency we have $det(A)=0$. Again, $A$ is non zero. Hence $1\le \rho(A) \le 2$. If $\rho(A)=1$, then $2 \le \rho(I+A) \le 4$. So, there is a possibility that $\rho(I+A)$ can be $2$. In this case, $I+A$ could not be invertible.

Am I correct ?

Comment: The only eigen value is $0$. ($Ax=\lambda x, x\neq 0$ implies $0=A^{k}x=\lambda^{k} x$). Since $-1$ is not an eigen value, $I+A$ is invertible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that $I+A$ is *always* invertible if $A$ is nilpotent. Suppose that $k$ is the minimum number such that $A^k = 0$. Now,

$$
(I+A)\sum_{i = 0}^k(-1)^iA^i = \sum_{i = 0}^k(-1)^iA^i + \sum_{i = 0}^k(-1)^iA^{i+1} = (-1)^0A^0 + (-1)^{k}A^{k+1} = I.
$$

In general in any (unital) ring $R$, if $a \in R$ is nilpotent then $1-a$ is invertible, with inverse

$$
\sum_{n \geq 0}a^n
$$

which is finite, since $a^k = 0$ for $k > n_0$ and some fixed $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$, and we note $a^0 = 1$. As an additional illustrative example, in the formal power series ring of $R$, the element $1-X$ is invertible with inverse $\sum_{i \geq 0}X^i$, since

$$
(1-X)\sum_{i \geq 0}X^i = \sum_{i \geq 0}X^i - \sum_{i \geq 0}X^{i+1} = 1. 
$$

Answer (score 7):

In any unital ring, if $a$ is nilpotent, then $1-a$ is invertible. This is
a standard argument: if $a^k=0$ then
$$1=1-a^k=(1-a)(1+a+\cdots+a^{k-1})=(1+a+\cdots+a^{k-1})(1-a).$$

In your example, $1=I$ and $a=-A$.